# Insert records into SQL Server that don't match 3 column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the following columns:

```
EntityID, BirthDate, FirstName, LastName
```

I have another SQL Server table with the following columns:

```
RG_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, BIRTHDATE
```

I want to import all records that don't have the same last name, first name & birthdate. They have to match all three values to be rejected.

Edit: Thanks to Ulysses for basically getting it (I think). Here is what I did:

```
Insert into [easi].[dbo].[Entity]
(FirstName, LastName, BirthDate)
SELECT
LastName = [ChurchWatch].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination].FAMILY_NAM
FirstName = [ChurchWatch].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination].FIRST_NAME
BirthDate = [ChurchWatch].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination].BIRTHDATE
From [ChurchWatch].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination]
Left Join [easi].[dbo].[Entity]
on [OLE DB Destination].FAMILY_NAM = [easi].[dbo].[Entity].LastName
and [ChurchWatch].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination].FIRST_NAME = [easi].[dbo]. 
[Entity].FirstName
and [ChurchWatch].[dbo].[OLE DB Destination].BIRTHDATE = [easi].[dbo]. 
[Entity].BirthDate;
```

Now it's giving me an error about "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AuditUtc' but that's a table requirement and I think I should be able to figure that one out.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I don't really know SQL, I just have a one off project to do that involves this.

Comment: SO is about helping you solve a specific technical issue - not writing your code for you. You need to find a tutorial and have a shot at it.

Comment: I'm just looking for an idea, I can figure it out once I know which direction to go

Comment: OK an idea would be to use `where not exists`

Comment: @AgentSmith, your question is not clear. From which table, you want to insert into which table ?

Comment: Thanks, I think I found something. I'll comment again if I have another roadblock.

Comment: @AgentSmith, if you found answer, please add your answer . Mark your answer so it is helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT INTO X
     (EntityID,LastName,FirstName,BirthDate)
    SELECT 
     EntityID = Y.RG_ID
    ,LastName = Y.LAST_NAME
    ,FirstName = Y.FIRST_NAME
    ,BirthDate = Y.BIRTHDATE
    FROM Y
    LEFT JOIN X
    ON Y.LAST_NAME = X.LastName
    AND Y.FIRST_NAME = X.FirstName
    AND Y.BIRTHDATE = X.BirthDate
    WHERE X.EntityID IS NULL;
```